# Is there a built-in function to convert multiple rows into a table in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 100 rows * 1 column data, how can I convert it into a 10*10 table in Excel without coding?

I am using Office 365.

Comment: I am using the latest version, Office 365

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Office 365 put this in the upper left cell of the desired position:

```
=INDEX(A1:A100,SEQUENCE(10,10))
```

Where `A1:A100` is the range of your data.

[image]

This will fill row by row.  If instead you want column by column, use TRANSPOSE.

```
=INDEX(A1:A100,TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(10,10)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, would you like to look at my updated question? Why it cannot work? Thank you!

Comment: Do not change the question after getting an answer. Instead ask a new question.