# Convert an Excel table into customised rows * columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to do something similar as [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1720318/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-convert-multiple-rows-into-a-table-in-excel), but got `#REF!` error. I want to convert it into customised rows * columns, e.g. convert the 3 * 4 table into 6 * 2 format. How to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: The issue why this approach is not working for you is that this approach requires that all numbers are in one column. Technically, you could achieve something like this using different approaches. It would be useful to understand how you want to distribute the numbers across the two columns. Do you want to have in column F, for example, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6 or 1-6?

Comment: I would like 1-6, thanks

Comment: Change the A1:D3 to A1:A12, you should covert the range to one column.

Comment: My raw data is already in a table format. Is there a direct way to convert any size of table into customised rows * columns?

Comment: Thank you, could you please also help me, how to make it 1,2,3,4,5,6 in the first column, and 7,8,9,10,11,12 in the second column?

Comment: Which approach did you use?

Comment: I mean option 1

Comment: @lanselibai I edited my response accordingly to address this feature. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach uses the very flexible `Let` function, which, however, is only available in Excel 365 and Excel 2021:

```
=LET(Matrix,$A$1:$D$3,rowsMatrix,ROWS(Matrix),colsMatrix,COLUMNS(Matrix),
cellValues,SEQUENCE((rowsMatrix*colsMatrix)/2,2,0),
INDEX(Matrix,INT(cellValues/colsMatrix)+1,MOD(cellValues,colsMatrix)+1))
```

---

***EDIT***: Additional Question in the Comments

In the approach described above, the matrix is distributed row-by-row among the columns, i.e., the first row starts with 1, 2, and so on.

To distribute the matrix by columns, i.e., column 1 has values 1-6 and column 2 has values 7-12, the `SEQUENCE` statement must be adjusted accordingly. In particular, the `SEQUENCE` statement controls the distribution mechanism, and you want to get a `SEQUENCE` that moves vertically rather than horizontally. Therefore, simply replace the `SEQUENCE` statement in the `LET` function with the following:

```
TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(2,(rowsMatrix*colsMatrix)/2,0))
```

If you want to understand to what extent the two `SEQUENCES` differ, simply enter the following formulas in Excel:

```
=SEQUENCE((3*4)/2,2,0)
=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(2,(3*4)/2,0))
```

---

Another tangible approach would be to transform the data into a single column via (where, e.g., $F$1 is the top cell of the target range):

Option 1:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW()-ROW($F$1))/COLUMNS($A$1:$D$1)),
MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),COLUMNS($A$1:$D$1)))
```

Option 2:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$3,INT((ROW()-ROW($F$1))/COLUMNS($A$1:$D$1))+1,
MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),COLUMNS($A$1:$D$1))+1)
```

Thus, both options 1 and 2 are simply helper columns to which you can then apply the function below. Since the function also works if you enter the entire column, this approach seems quite flexible as well:

```
=INDEX($F:$F,SEQUENCE(6,2))
```

Comment: A future release [excel formula release](https://insider.office.com/en-us/blog/text-and-array-manipulation-functions-in-excel) could see TOCOL() and WRAPCOLS() formulas which would do this transformation.